# JS React GLTF loader query parameters

Tags: three.js, azure-blob-storage

I have the `.gltf` and `.bin` files in a azure storage account. Downloading these files requires a SAS URI that follows the pattern: `https://<saName>.blob.core.windows.net/<pathToBlob>?<sas>`. While I build a `SAS` that is valid for downloading both the `.gltf` and `.bin` files, I am running into an issue where I specify the `.gltf` URL to the `useGLTF` hook. That call goes through, but when fetching the `.bin` file, under the hood the loader is dropping the query params, resulting in a URL `https://<saName>.blob.core.windows.net/<pathToBin>` which fails.

Is there a way to make the loader keep the query parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into this, you can use the [setURLModifier()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html?q=loading#api/en/loaders/managers/LoadingManager.setURLModifier). In my case, this looks as:

```js
    const { scene, animations } = useGLTF(props.path, false, false, (loader) => {
        loader.manager.setURLModifier((url) => {
            # alter the URL and return the new value
            return url;
        })
    });
```